# How to unit test database based algorithm? (php)

Tags: php, unit-testing

so far, it's "easy" to test something, but this time I need to test an algorithm based on database source. The database should be filled for that, but is there a good, working way to do it?

Comment: sqlfiddle perhaps? :) of course that can only test queries.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're after but have you checked the database section of the PHPUnit docs? http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is really an integration test.

You would need to ensure that your test can set up the required data and clean up after itself to keep the tests repeatable. I normally [create the database / tables as part of the test set-up](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201110/Blog/Database-Integration-Testing-With-Enhance-PHP/), then drop them when I'm done, which is easier than trying to get a table back into a particular state.